# Export an HTML table to Excel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, excel, export

I have made an application which populates a table based on a JSON-dataset and I would like to store the data I filter to a Excel file (or CSV even). I have two script files, app.js and mainController.js (separating to get cleaner code), one view and the index file (and bootstrap of course). Here's the app.js:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module('customAudience', ['ngRoute']);

  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        controller: 'mainController',
        templateUrl: 'views/mainPage.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });

  app.factory('Excel', function ($window) {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-
html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions>
<x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets>
</x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body>
</html>',
    base64 = function (s) {
      return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
    },
    format = function (s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    };
  return {
    tableToExcel: function (tableId, worksheetName) {
      var table = $(tableId),
        ctx = {
          worksheet: worksheetName,
          table: table.html()
        },
        href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
      return href;
    }
  };
});
}());
```

and here is my mainController.js:

```
(function () {

  var mainController = function ($scope, $http, Excel, $timeout) {

    $scope.sortType = 'PhoneNumber'; //set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse = false; //set the default sort order
    $scope.searchElement = ''; //set the default search/filter term

    $scope.items = [];
    $http.get('data/data.json').then(function (response) {
      $scope.items = response.data;
    });

    $scope.exportToExcel = function (tableId) { // ex: '#my-table'
      $scope.exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel(tableId, 'sheet name');
      $timeout(function () {
        location.href = $scope.fileData.exportHref;
      }, 100); // trigger download
    };
  };


  angular.module('customAudience').controller('mainController', 
['$scope', '$http', 'Excel', '$timeout', mainController]);

}());
```

I have an id on my table that says "mytable" and this is passed into the function.

The error I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'exportHref' of undefined
>       at mainController.js:19
>       at angular.js:17855
>       at e (angular.js:5507)
>       at angular.js:5784*

I've used https://gist.github.com/umidjons/352da2a4209691d425d4 as a guide, but it's no go.

Have anyone of you guys exported a HTML table to Excel in AngularJS?

Am I missing something?

Note that I am using a Mac, should that make any difference?

Is there another, more clean, method of exporting the data - like a CSV file?

Comment: Just using window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + yourHTMLTableNodes) will create an excel in non IE browsers. Only thing that might be an issue is that you''l have to resave the exel the first time you open it in excel. Using the namespaced schema is technically better, but way more complicated. Making a csv file would work too obv, and is rather trivial.

Comment: @Shilly Do you know of an elegant solution to this issue, exporting to CSV?

Comment: Put all the data you need into a string or array, add commas between everything. Use window.open(data:application ...... ) with a text/plain type. Alternatively open the text into a new tab, then use document.execCommand("SaveAs") to open the dialog window to save it. Alternatively make a text file serverside and serve it to the user.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in $scope.exportToExcel method the location.href value by $scope.exportHref; without fileData.

```
$timeout(function () { location.href = $scope.exportHref; }, 100); // trigger download
```

that works for me.